# Anguar2-Material2: Want to setup a fixed sidenav below toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm learning angular2 and material2. I'm trying to make small website which has simple toolbar and a fixed sidenav. I have created toolbar but sidenav is not working as expected. I'm just using below plunker code for learning.

```
    <md-toolbar color="primary">
  Angular Material 2 App
</md-toolbar>
<md-sidnav-layout>
  <md-sidenav>
    <md-nav-list>
      <a md-list-item>
            Test1
       </a>

    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>
</md-sidnav-layout>
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lb8ZsgpLhtSmPvFXZWk4?p=preview)

Can you please help me on creating a fixed navigation bar. or Am I doing anything wrong?  I'm following angular/material2 code for example.

Answer (score 9):

I think what you want is:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
    <button md-icon-button (click)="start.toggle()">
        Click
    </button>
    <span>Toolbar</span>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-container>
    <md-sidenav #start mode="side" opened="true">
        Entry
    </md-sidenav>
    <div class="demo-sidenav-content">
        hey there!
    </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Try here: https://plnkr.co/edit/7DyjwRc5ygoyraitGEsv?p=preview

Edit: For a permanently opened sidenav just use `mode="side" opened="true"`. See above.

Comment: Thanks Mario Eis!! for your help. Actually what i 'm thinking is, I don't want any click action, instead of that the sidebar should be visible at all the time under toolbar. That's what I'm trying. Please advice me if you could.

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer and the plnkr to fit your needs. If you don't need the button, just remove it from the template. If it answers your question, please accept the answer :)